# Lie Bracket explicit computation

Tags: lie-algebras

I'm at the beginning of learning about Lie Brackets, and the book I'm working out of explicitly calculates $Zf = [X,Y]f$ (where $X,Y$ are vector fields) as follows:
\begin{align*}
Zf & = [X,Y]f \\
& = (XY-YX)f \\
& = X(Yf)-Y(Xf) \\
& = X(Y^a\partial_af)-Y(X^a\partial_a f) \\
& = X^b\partial_b (Y^a\partial_a f)-Y^b\partial_b(X^a\partial_a f) \\
& \stackrel{!}{=} (X^b\partial_bY^a-Y^b\partial_bX^a)\partial_af -X^aY^b(\partial_b\partial_af-\partial_a\partial_b f)
\end{align*}
At ! I'm unsure of how the second term of this is derived.
I know I have to use chain rule on $\partial_b(Y^a\partial_a f)$ and the corresponding part of the other term, but when I do this I get:
\begin{align*}
X^b\partial_b(Y^a\partial_a f)-Y^b\partial_b(X^a\partial_a f) & = X^b(\partial_b Y^a\partial_a f+Y^a\partial_b\partial_a f)-Y^b(\partial_b X^a\partial_a f+X^a\partial_b\partial_a f) \\
& = (X^b\partial_b Y^a-Y^b\partial_b X^a)\partial_a f+X^bY^b\partial_b\partial_af-Y^bX^a\partial_b\partial_a f
\end{align*}
If I have that $$X^bY^a\partial_b\partial_a f-Y^bX^a\partial_b\partial_a f = -X^aY^b(\partial_b\partial_a f-\partial_a\partial_b f)$$
I'm done.  This equality isn't clear to me though, and I'd appreciate an explaination of it.
It's also possible I misapplied chain rule or something silly.

Comment: @mfl My mistake. I'm still unsure how the final equality holds.

Comment: Yes, because the book immediately uses the equality of mixed partial derivatives to say the term is $0$.

Comment: Ray D'inverno [__Introducing Einstein's Relativity__](http://documents.mx/documents/ray-dinverno-introducing-einsteins-relativitypdf.html) on page 66 (page 72 of the slideshow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
\begin{align}
X^bY^a\partial_b\partial_a f-Y^bX^a\partial_b\partial_a f &\\ &= X^aY^b\partial_a\partial_b f-X^aY^b\partial_b\partial_a f &\\ &= X^aY^b(\partial_a\partial_b f-\partial_b\partial_a f) &\\ &= -X^aY^b(\partial_b\partial_a f-\partial_a\partial_b. f)\end{align} where we have used

$$X^bY^a\partial_b\partial_a f=X^aY^b\partial_a\partial_b f$$ by changing indices.

Comment: My main question here is why do we have that $-Y^bX^a\partial_b\partial_a f = -X^aY^b\partial_b\partial_a f$?  I understand this all if I can justify this, but so far don't know how to justify it.

Comment: Note that $X^a$ and $Y^b$ are real numbers and thus $Y^bX^a=X^aY^b$ for any $a,b.$

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was missing.